# Roses fading their color

Tags: identification, flowers, roses

Can anyone help me how to look after these roses. Their color is fading and their petals have some spots on. Should I cut off the dying roses and if yes how should I do that.

This is how it was earlier this summer [image]
And this is how it is now [image][image][image][image]
Also it has this plant ( I cant identify it ), which I didnt plant, 
growing near it. 
[image]

Thank you in advance

P.S It receives full sun throughout the day and I water it almost every day

Update: I cut off most of the roses and some leaves as I was adviced and this is how it looks now. Thank you

[image][image][image]

Comment: You've just dead headed and thinned!  Excellent, Claire.  (rent a pressure washer to clean out the pavers, they need to be tightened and edged down the road a bit).  Beautiful rose.

Comment: And don't water everyday unless it is very hot.  Those pavers accumulate heat and on hot hot days with wind the water in that soil will evaporate quickly.  Best test is to dig down into the soil and pull up a paver close to the edge of this rose to check moisture in the soil .  I would pull up more pavers to expose more soil permanently.  More exposure to air less chance of rot.  You need to see and touch the soil to monitor this plant's needs more closely.  If that soil is still wet from the last watering, do not water again until drier.  Would this make a walkway too narrow?

Comment: Looks like it would on the east side of this plant?  Just open the west and south more by pulling the pavers up to store somewhere else.  It looks like if you pulled the pavers  2 feet from the foundation to 'connect to the next roses?  That would be best for plants as well as your foundation.

Comment: You can do this yourself, those pavers will need some sort of edging to stop your pavers from 'slipping'.  The foundation should never have been used for that purpose.  There should be pressure treated lumber defining the edge next you your home with space between the lumber and your foundation.  The pavers should not touch the foundation.  As long as you've got positive drainage this shouldn't become an issue.  I'd like to know what these pavers were laid upon.  The depth of gravel, then sand.  Looks like a super job, just getting older in need of reinforcement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claire, your little rose bush is beautiful.  It needs to be pruned and flowers need to be removed.  What have you added as fertilizer?

First, the basic thing to understand about flowers is that they are temporary, meant to attract pollinators.  Once the flower has been pollinated that flower starts dying.  It has done its job.

Reproductive growth takes lots of energy, carbohydrates made by the chlorophyll in the leaves and some stems.  Fertilizer is not a 'boost'  Fertilizer is not food.  Fertilizer added in just the correct amount (balanced plain old NPK) not too little and certainly not too much is critical for all plants according to their own specific needs.

This rose is showing some weird symptoms; top of the plant looks healthyish and the bottom looks anemic or has been blocked from sunlight.  Need to know what you've added.

Get used to deadheading all flowers.  The basic principle is flowering takes lots of energy and if you aren't in the seed making business cutting off those flowers as soon as you can stomach cutting off flowers, is the best for your plant.  If this were an annual, an annual having but one goal in this life- to set seed-once seed is allowed to set that plant actually starts dying.

Your rose is a perennial but the basics still apply.  A plant that has set seed now has to use more energy abscising the seed, useless leaves and stems.  So if you cut them off sooner again, you are saving energy expenditure for your plant making it healthier, more robust and able to fight off disease and insect problems.

Black spot is a great example of a plant taking care of a disease of fungus.  The plant sequesters, quarantines the fungus by cutting off the area infected by the fungus. Looking at it under a microscope is amazing.  Surgically precise separation between the healthy leaf and the infected leaf inside the circle or boundary. Cut off from water and chemistry (versus 'nutrients') the infected part of the leaf drops out of the leaf, causing a 'hole' in the leaf.

Black spot is common and can be found on the healthiest roses and many other plants.  A healthy plant is able to take care of itself.  Adding fertilizer, not compost, is as important as light and water and drainage.  Compost is for soil tilth, not fertilizer or soil replacement.  "Less is best   More is death  and None is dumb"...ugh, my little ditty about adding balanced fertilizer, it might help to remember!

Use alcohol to clean your 'by pass pruners' (don't use anvil type pruners), even good kitchen shears are fine, but clean with alcohol first.  Snip the lesser branch from its host branch or the main stem/trunk as close as you are able.  Try not to leave big stumps.  Remove branches that are angled into the side of your home. Remove branches that are so buried under other leaves that their leaves are unable to receive any light for photosynthesis thus allowing other leaves to do a better job for the entire plant.

Start with one or two branches and take pictures to send to us.  Remove the weight of the 'trusses' of flowers...ahhhhh...from a branch and watch the branch bounce upwards again.

Flowers die.  The first sign is fading, petal fall, blackening of the center and the making of seed is underway.  Major energy expenditure.  Cutting off flowers sends all that energy of making seed back into your plant to make more flowers, more lush leaves.

Has this plant been moved recently? Or was something moved away from this plant?

This rose must be a climber or a spray mini rose.  I think a support might help it an awful lot.  The more air you can keep going over the leaves of your plant the less you need to worry about fungus.   Spreading the branches on a trellis is the best way to show off this plant and increase ventilation!  Get used to cutting off flowers, to have MORE flowers and better health for the plant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should deadhead. You need a pair of sharp, clean secateurs (not sure if that's what they're called if you're in the States) and you can either wait till a whole truss has faded flowers, or nip off the spent flowers and then cut off the whole truss when all the flowers are faded. When you cut the truss off, take it back to a leaf, removing the whole stem that held the truss.

You haven't said what type of rose, so it's hard to know whether it is repeat flowering or not, but if it is, its really important to remove spent flowers before they form seedpods.

The spots on the petals of the flowers are probably from rain - some roses show these marks after rain, (or if you water overhead and it hits the flowers) others don't. I'm unable to see any evidence of black spot myself.

Pruning is a separate procedure done usually in late winter/early spring, but it does depend on the variety of rose. That deep coloured shoot growing up  the wall in the final picture might be a sucker off the rootstock, or it might be just a new shoot from above the roots -  check its point of origin. If its below soil level, wrench it off; if it's coming from a stem near the base of the plant, its meant to be there.

Comment: I think you are right Bamboo on that sucker, root stock.  Beautiful rose!  I can see 'rose hips'.

Comment: @stormy I can't see rose hips  - I can see where spent flowers have shed all their petals and gone brown in the centre, but no actual hips yet. Might not form hips, some modern cultivars don't. Rose manure isn't a term we use normally for such a product linked to below, its usually known as 'rose food' or 'rose fertilizer' in the UK, cos its in a box and has an NPK readout

Comment: Thanks, I figured.  Isn't a rose hip the seed of a rose flower or is that for special roses?  Or is that farther down the line?

Comment: @stormy - a rose hip is a distinctive looking seedcase - some roses are grown simply for their large and decorative hips, but not all roses form these.

Answer (score 1):

Your rose is congested and needs to be pruned.
The plant has to feed all its-foliage plus all the flowers as well... tough job.
This clearly stressing the plant and it’s started to show 2 things:

Lighter coloured leaves, that’s overwatering and lack of nutrients.

Black spot, which is not good and will need to be treated to contraint it.

If you let me know what time of rose it is, I can advice on pruning and when.

A quick rose liquid feed will give it a helping hand but rose manure, lightly worked into the pot is best.

Treating information for black spot is rose clear. Easy to use, late at night or early mornings to avoid killing beneficial insects. However, this is a last resort because the disease is not too bad and can be worked out(for now) with pruning.

[rose manure](http://m.molevalleyfarmers.com/h5/r/molevalleyfarmers//mvf/store/products/westland-rose-food-3kg?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlbm075ja2wIV4bvtCh3u2wqyEAQYASABEgKgGvD_BwE)

Comment: What is 'rose manure'?

Comment: It’s just the right mix of nutrients for good rose health. I have added a link. Many products are available.