# Is this a climbing rose?

Tags: flowers, roses, overwintering

I had this rose bush for a few years and I used to cut it back in winter. Two years ago it grew some long stems and I decided to let them and see if they can survive winter, which they did and they had beautiful blooms by the end of spring. Now it keeps growing and I was just wondering if anyone can tell if this is a climbing rose?

[image]

[image]

P.S. Here is the earlier post I made about this rose
[Roses fading their color](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39320/roses-fading-their-color)

Comment: do the flowers come all at once, last for about six weeks, then it stops flowering till next year? Or does it keep producing flowers throughout  the growing season?

Comment: The flowers come all at once in spring and then it keeps producing more flowers but not as much as the first time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a climbing rose, its growth habit suggests it's not, combined with the major flush of smaller flowers, with a lesser, ongoing display; these features are not typical of climbing roses. I was wondering about a rambling rose, which fits with the major flush of flowers, again not huge blooms but masses of them, and with sporadic flowers later, but the later flowers would only be sporadic and not that many.  It might well be a shrub rose - these vary in height between 5-15 feet depending on variety, and tend to have a slightly sprawling growth habit, which yours is exhibiting, so on balance, I'd suspect a shrub rose.

Some information on various types of roses here https://www.thespruce.com/types-of-roses-4069722